# What does $P_c (\vec{x})_c = \vec{x}$ mean in plain english?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, matrix-equations, change-of-basis

Based on a [3 Blue 1 Brown explanation](https://youtu.be/P2LTAUO1TdA?t=418), a matrix of x (ie. $P_c  \vec{x}$) , where $P_c = \begin{bmatrix}
2 & -1\\
1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$ and $\vec{x} = \begin{bmatrix}
1\\
2
\end{bmatrix}$, it does two things:

1. Geometrically: it allows us to transform our grid into someone else's grid(In this example someone = Jennifer).
2. Numerically: it transforms Jennifer's language into our language. Meaning, exact same vector but, written like how we(in the standard basis) will write them.

[image]

My question is, is that logic correct, and can that same logic apply if we sub $\vec{x}$ with $(\vec{x})_c$ like so: $P_c (\vec{x})_c = \vec{x}$?

Comment: In the interest of making the question self-contained, could you please edit the question body to add brief explanations of the notation $P_cx$ and $(x)_c$?

Comment: No problem, thanks @AndrewD.Hwang, added.

Comment: Thanks! In terms of semantics, is $P_c$ the transition matrix from the standard basis to some other basis, and does $(x)_c$ denote the coordinate vector of $x$ with respect to that basis?

Comment: Thank you. Yes to both! $P_c$ is the transition matrix from the standard basis (Our grid). And $(\vec{x})_c$ is the coordinates of $\vec{x}$ with respect to C basis